# Maintained open source offline Japanese dictionary for Android?

Tags: android, open-source, offline, dictionary

I am using [Aedict 2.9](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.baka.aedict) because I want an open source Japanese dictionary which works even when offline.

However, recently, [Aedict 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.baka.aedict3) has switched to a proprietary model it seems, and I would like to stick to open source.

Apart from sticking with Aedict 2.9 forever and maintaining it for myself as a fork, what other open source options are there?

Requirements:

- Open source
- Runs on Android
- I can look up a Japanese word, and it shows the definition in English.
- English to Japanese not strictly necessary

Comment: I don't know why there's still no answer. Maybe you've not been clear concerning your requirements (functionality etc)? Can't hurt to [edit] that in, as in a side-effect your question pops up on page 1 then (activity) :)

Comment: How could an open source app turn into a proprietary app? That's not possible by the definition of open source.

Comment: @Turion The copyright holder doesn't have to abide by the terms of the open source license, so they can make a new closed source version.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that [QuickDic](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=quickdic&fdid=com.hughes.android.dictionary) has an excellent interface, works offline and you can download English-Japanese and lots of other dictionaries, which are generated from http://wiktionary.org.

In general, if you're looking for open source android apps, you should look on F-Droid.

Answer (score 0):

## [Akebi Japanese Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.craxic.akebifree)

Features:

- Search for Kanji and words and define them in English
- English to Japanese search
- Offline

I don't see why it wouldn't be open source, because it has:

> - No DRM
>
> Because it just makes everyone angry!
>
> - No Ads
>
> Because they kill battery life!

It's ambiguous whether it's maintained. The last update was in March 7, 2014. Still, the app developer replies to recent comments.

Comment: It is not open source. This is a central requirement.